# Pass data-url attribute to jQuery ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, custom-data-attribute

I have a form with a data-attribute containing a URL to an API JSON file:

```
<form class="product" action="#" data-url="dist/scripts/main.js">
    [...]
</form>
```

I want to pass the URL from the data attribute into an Ajax call in an external script.

external.js:

```
var apiUrl = $('.product').data('url');
console.log(apiUrl) // This returns the correct URL set above

$.ajax(apiUrl).done(function(data) {
    [...]
});
```

I even condensed it like this and same result:

```
$.ajax($('.product').data('url')).done(function(data) {
    [...]
});
```

When I do this, my doing a feedback loop, possibly because of the (data) parameter that's being used in the ajax function.

Error: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` referring to a line that contains `currentPosition = data.Positions[0].Position;`

I'm not sure why the URL isn't passing to the ajax function correctly.

Comment: Where is your external.js in your html file? Make sure it's loaded after the dom is loaded.

Comment: @Garuuk It's at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag. The ajax function is contained in a document ready function.

Comment: check your console. Do you see an API call being made?  Is your ajax being called by a button/listener event?

Comment: @Garuuk The console error that keeps displaying infinitely says, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined(…)` which is referring to a line that contains this: `currentPosition = data.Positions[0].Position;`. I don't understand why this could be throwing an error.

Comment: You need to display your entire code if you want help. What you posted is fine.  It looks like you have other code we can't see causing this.

Comment: This was an unfortunate user error. I was not using the correct JSON file in the data-url attribute so it was throwing an error since it wasn't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/RT0cHEAjDHFssXg2YbC4?p=preview

It works here - you can see the 404 in console. Make sure you load external.js after the dom loads. In this case it's just script.js Or you can use the $( document ).ready()

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <form class="product" action="#" data-url="dist/scripts/main.js">
    <input type="text">

  </form>
 <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```